# whats the best way to compare two csv file and put the difference in a new file in php

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to compare between two csv file and put the difference between both files in a new file. Do you guys have any idea whats the approach to do this?

Each of this file will consist of 30k lines.

Comment: Why don't use simple loop? Read one line from the first file, read one line from the second file, compare lines, write diffrence to the third file, unset lines' variables, go to the next iteration. The thing is to read only one line from each file in one moment, not the whole file.

Comment: How many columns? seems a bit excessive for php...

Comment: there will be more than 30k rows and around 10 to 20 cols

Answer (score 0):

Read the two CSV files into two arrays, and use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

I'm going on this assumption that the two files are vastly similar, because I don't know the structure of the CSV files that you are looking to compare.

Comment: Yes, these two file will be similar. Just some value of it might be different. Such as first.csv has date 10/11/2017 and second csv with date 11/11/2017.
But they will have similar id. (id, date -> 1, 10/11/2017)
I need to update the first csv file to use second csv file's date.